# Manga in which the main character works for a company with a female CEO and travels to different virtual reality or dream worlds

Tags: story-identification, manga

If I remember correctly, this manga had the word 'dream' in the title.

It involved the main protagonist entering either a virtual reality space or dream space. He would supposedly have to complete the world in the space to return to his body and he would gain some sort of power from it. There is some sort of error in this space and a woman enters it as well. This woman is the CEO of the main character's company. The first space takes the form of an ice age. He and that woman live together within a house there. After that dream was accomplished he gained a throwing ability.

Later on, he finds a ring or artifact left by the creator of the dream space. He also enters a apocalyptic world on the brink of destruction and another woman appeared in that dream space. The woman might have been the CEO's rival company CEO. I do not remember the third dream space, but the woman who showed up was an idol singer. Also, he is the only one supposed to be able to remember anything from that space but obviously, the women remember as well.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main character gained throwing ability after finishing the dream then it was *Dreamland Adventure* chapter 21.

[Mangaupdate: *Dreamland Adventure*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/mwjze2w/dreamland-adventure)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).